# Need to combine two list in scala with some condition for replacement

Tags: list, scala

I want to do this :

```
val list1 = List(Student("ivan","history",45))

val list2 = List(Student("ivan","history",40),Student("alexander","physics",81),Student("vlad","math",70))
```

I want to combine list1 and list2 so that list1's element remove list's 2 element based on student name and subject.

**Required Output :**

```
List(Student("ivan","history",45),Student("alexander","physics",81),Student("vlad","math",70))
```

Comment: Could you please add the code you've written, with the current output. Because here you're just asking us to do your homework

Comment: Since this looks like a homework, it would be good if you can tell us if you have any restrictions. Like you can only use lists _(not any other datastructure)_, or if you have to do it using recursion or whatever. Also, please, please, include the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for a `groupBy` here. You concatenate the two lists, then you `groupBy` and take the head element for each key. This will scrumble the order among students though, but is efficient.

```scala
(list1 ++ list2)
  .groupBy(s => (s.name, s.subject))
  .map { case (key, values) => 
    values.head
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to check if two Student values match:

```
def isSame(s: Student, t: Student): Boolean = (s.name == t.name && s.sub == t.sub)
```

Using this you can iterate over `list2` and check if there is a match in `list1`. If there is, you use the value from `list1` else keep the value from `list2`.

```
list2.map(s2 => (list1.map(s1 => if (isSame(s1, s2)) s1 else s2))).flatten
```

Note that this might not be the most optimal solution if the two lists are huge.